# Bigquery - INSERT into Existing table - from local CSV

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, insert

In Bigquery - I want to create a table, then load the table from a csv file on my local drive in a single query.
I know the Statements below are not correct, looking for an exmaple of how to do it.
I can create the table,  I am not able to insert,  or is there another method (upsert, merge???)

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Project1.DataSet_Creation.tbl_Store_List_Full
( Store_Nbr string(255),Sister_Store string(255))
,
INSERT INTO Project1.DataSet_Creation.tbl_Store_List_Full (Store_Nbr,Sister_Store)
FROM  C:\GCP_Transition\tbl_Store_List_Full.csv

Comment: For a single csv-file, which is not large, you can use the BigQuery UI. For larger one, please upload it to a bucket in the cloud storage (gcs). For several csv-files, which do all have the same format (same columns), see [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/google-cloud-storage-gcs-to-bigquery-the-simple-way-4bb74216b8c8): `CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE mydataset.mytable
OPTIONS (
  format = 'CSV',
  uris = ['gs://mybucket/*.csv']
)`

Comment: Thank you Samuel,  this is very cool,  I was able to play with it a bit,  unfortunately it still leaves me with the wrong data types in my columns,  but very cool none the less, and I learned a new trick.  Thanks again to all

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, for this purpose you need to use the Bigquery web UI, in a project tab click the create table and choose the CSV file as upload method, enable the auto detect if it is disabled and header rows to skip as 1 so that Bigquery will take your columns as proper of the CSV file with no title row as the docs suggest.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table

Comment: AfAIK,  thank you for your response,  I have used the UI,  it does not detect the data types correctly, so you  have to manually define each column, which is not too bad for a small two column table,  but some tables have a hundred columns, and it is not a great solution.

Comment: Thank you for your responce,  one problem I have had, is the data in several of the columns looks like numbers, but they need to be imported as STRING. and auto detect is not helping me in those instance,  I have resorted to added text "ABCD" into the columns to attemp to trick it, it kind of works. but still not ideal

Comment: This does not work in most cases. The Auto schema read is terrible: always gets zip_codes wrong. Always. If you have to repeatedly import a 100 column table it will add an hour to each load.